# How to run code using crontab on raspberry pi

Tags: python, linux, cron, raspberry-pi, xbee

I have to run code on the boot of raspberrypi. I am doing using this by below command

```
@reboot while true; do timeout 600 python3 TestProgram.py; sleep 4; done &
```

My program is not running. Please suggest me some corrections. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some codes on this link.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md

```
@reboot python /home/pi/myscript.py
```

You need to save your python file in the folder '/home/pi/'

Comment: Thanks sir. I was not giving the path of the file. But, it is required to put & at last always. I donot know why?